# how to fetch request with updated information without adding it in dependency array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

fetchedAuthor is a author object. isFollow is his follower count. when someone clicks on folow isFollow changes. when isFollow changes i want to rerun useEffect. when the author changes, the fetchedAuthor changes but i dont want this useEffect to reRun as this is strictly for follower handling not author handling but at the same time when the author changes i want this useEfffect to know that author has changed so the next time when isFollow changes the useEffect doesnt fetch with the previous fetchedAuthor but the latest value of fetchedAuthor.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentAuthor(fetchedAuthor) ;
  },[fetchedAuthor]) ;

 useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`URL/${currentAuthor}/${isFollow}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }},[isFollow]) ;
```

would this help me to get the appropriate response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ref to store the current `fetchedAuthor`. Update the ref whenever `fetchedAuthor` changes. Use the ref's value when calling the api:

```
const authorRef = useRef(fetchedAuthor);

useEffect(() => {
  authorRef.current = fetchedAuthor;
}, [fetchedAuthor]);

useEffect(async() => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`URL/${authorRef.current}/${isFollow}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}, [isFollow]);
```